# Search the dropdown values with the input box

Tags: angular

I have a bootstrap drop down where it is generating the account names from the response API, As the Account names grows it is hard to find the particular account from the drop down list.

How can i perform a search operation with the input box and show the account name which is searched in the input tag. Along with the name response has a data associated with the account.

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select</button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search">
      <li  *ngFor="let project of cloudAccountList" (click) = "changeCloudAccount(project)" [value]="project.accountId"><a  >
      <span *ngIf="project.masterAccount === true" class="badge" style="background:#f08519">M</span> {{ project.accountName }}</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

the response json:

```
"data": {
    "cloudBoList": [
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 1,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 123,
        "externalId": "123",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account Name 1",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "xyz",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": true,
        "billingBucket": "billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "123",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 178,
        "externalId": "456",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account name 2",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "abc",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": false,
        "billingBucket": "2-billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "456",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 178,
        "externalId": "456",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account name 3",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "abc",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": false,
        "billingBucket": "2-billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "456",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 178,
        "externalId": "456",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account name 4",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "abc",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": false,
        "billingBucket": "2-billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "456",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 178,
        "externalId": "456",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account name 5",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "abc",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": false,
        "billingBucket": "2-billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "456",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 0,
        "accountId": 2,
        "customerName": null,
        "cloudAccountId": 178,
        "externalId": "456",
        "awsAccountId": 456,
        "accountName": "Account name 6",
        "aggId": 1,
        "accessKey": "abc",
        "secretkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "arn": "arn",
        "isMasterAccount": false,
        "isCrossAccount": true,
        "aispl": false,
        "billingBucket": "2-billing-bucket",
        "region": "region",
        "cloudAccountStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "refNumber": "456",
        "createdDate": 0,
        "isCurEnable": false,
        "reportName": null,
        "curArray": null,
        "crossAccount": true,
        "masterAccount": false,
        "curEnable": false
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/searchboxdropdown?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) application. How can i search the account name in the input box along with the account details associated with the account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a `filter()` function on change of Search textbox, and filter items

Try like this:

.ts

```
filteredCloudAccountList:any

constructor() {
   ...
   this.filteredCloudAccountList = [...this.cloudAccountList]
}


filter(searchText) {
    this.filteredCloudAccountList = this.cloudAccountList.filter(item => item.accountName.includes(searchText))
}
```

.html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="filter($event)"placeholder="Search" >

<li  *ngFor="let project of filteredCloudAccountList" >
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/searchboxdropdown-z2rhq9?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: i updated the code here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/searchboxdropdown?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) it is not working

Comment: You forgot to change the `<li  *ngFor="let project of filteredCloudAccountList" >`. You need to display `filteredCloudAccountList`, not `cloudAccountList`

Comment: Also you didn't add `this.filteredCloudAccountList = [...this.cloudAccountList]` in constructor

Comment: @Santhosh Can you check the demo I shared

Comment: Check the working code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e792uh

Comment: @AdritaSharma this is not working as this is case sensitive if the name is in upper case i have to search with the UPPER case can this be made case insensitive.

Comment: Just use `toLowerCase()`

Comment: ` item.accountName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())`

Comment: API response have the account name starting with capital Letter ('Xyz company') i have to search 'Xyz' not 'xyz' the above example works if i have my response in lower letter @AdritaSharma

Comment: What is your requirement? If you type `xyz` will it show or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe to filter cloudAccountList.

From your StackBliz

**app.component.html**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="search">
        <li *ngFor="let project of cloudAccountList | filter: search" (click)="changeCloudAccount(project)"
            [value]="project.accountId"><a>
                <span *ngIf="project.masterAccount === true" class="badge" style="background:#f08519">M</span>
                {{ project.accountName }}</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**filter.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: any[], searchText: string): any[] {
    if(!items) return [];
    if(!searchText) return items;
    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();
    return items.filter( it => {
       return it.accountName.toLowerCase().includes(searchText);
    });
   }
}
```

Also In **App.Module.ts** declarations include **FilterPipe**

**EDIT:**
A working StalkBliz for the same here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e792uh